# How to override preventDefault/stopPropagation in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I am writing a Firefox addon (in Javascript) and have a need to override the preventDefault and stopPropagation on all the Event objects (Keyboard, Mouse, HTML, ...). I intend to call the original functions, but want to be notified when those functions have been called by the web application.

Any pointers on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Never figured out how to intercept the stopPropagation and preventDefault on Event objects, however, my intention was to be notified if preventDefault has been invoked on an event that I dispatched (in my Firefox addon), I can look at the return value of dispatchEvent to find out if preventDefault was invoked. That satisfies my requirement for now.